# ffmpeg not working on big videos on browser

Tags: javascript, video, ffmpeg, encoding, webassembly

I am using the @ffmpeg/ffmpeg package in the browser and it works for small videos (2MB) but it doesn't work for a video that is 10MB.

I got this error: RuntimeError: abort(OOM). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.

The relevant code that I am using is that one:

```js
import { createFFmpeg, fetchFile } from "@ffmpeg/ffmpeg";

const ffmpeg = createFFmpeg({
  corePath: "https://unpkg.com/@ffmpeg/core@0.11.0/dist/ffmpeg-core.js",
  log: true,
});


function Home() {
  // ...

  useEffect(() => {
    ffmpeg.load().then(() => setReady(true));
  }, []);

  const handleUpload = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    ffmpeg.FS("writeFile", "input.mov", await fetchFile(file));
    await ffmpeg.run("-i", "input.mov", "output.mp4");
    const data = ffmpeg.FS("readFile", "output.mp4");
    const compressedVideo = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([data.buffer], { type: "video/mp4" })
    );
    setCompressedVideo(compressedVideo);
  };

  // ...
}
```

Comment: OOM means "Out Of Memory". You may hit some configuration limit. But why to load the entire file at a time?

Comment: What is this configuration limit and how can I change it?

Comment: We have absolutely no idea on what you are using. And if you have no control on them, it is a bad idea. Do not expect browsers will allow code to expand limits (it would be one of the worse idea)

Comment: You think 10MB is too much to be processed by the browser using webassembly?

Comment: It is not 10MB. 10MB is just one file. It will need a second one, and some intermediary steps (to compress/encode the program will try several parameters and it will decide what it is best. If there is bandwidth limits (depending on output format), it should keep much more information in memory to increase compression if later it is required to have more data (e.g. change of scene). And all libraries and compilers will takes memory. Encoding was always a task for special hardware or high end machines for a reason.

Comment: Out of memory uncaught runtime error is [a real problem](https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm/issues?q=OOM) for this port of ffmpeg.